# Is double milled flour the same as 00 type flour?

Tags: baking, bread, flour

Is double milled flour the same as 00 type flour ? I want to buy some semolina 00 type flour but I can find only double milled semolina flour ? Are they the same ?

Comment: Welcome to the cooking stack. I think this might well have been answered on here before , so does this answer your question? [What is 00 flour and when should I use?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27950/what-is-00-flour-and-when-should-i-use)

Comment: @bob1 How would that answer the question? It doesn’t even mention “double-milled flour”.

Comment: @Sneftel See the answer with score of 2 from Melara

Comment: @bob1 I did. It doesn’t mention it.

Comment: @Sneftel it mentions that the different grades are different degrees of milling with the the finest being 000. Now, I'm aware that it doesn't specifically mention double milling, but the implication is that it doesn't have to be double milled to be 00.

Answer (score 3):

No, double milled flour is not 00 flour. The 00 on flour is a measure of the milling fineness, this does not indicate that it has been double milled. In fact, I can find a number of sites that sell both 00 and double milled flour, such as [this one](https://eurousa.com/products/flour/) (no endorsement or relationship with the company, merely one of many).

Double milled flour is flour that has been [through a milling process twice](https://www.millingfresh.com/top-tips-for-fresh-flour/). The size of the flour will be dependent on the mill size, ranging from 2-000, with 000 being the finest. Often double milling is done with a coarser size to start with and a finer size for the second mill. This produces a consistent mill and keeps the temperature in the milling process low, meaning that the proteins stay intact, so produce good gluten development.

Comment: From my research there are different names for soft wheat (Triticum aestivum)  and hard wheat(durum or triticum durum) . 2, 1,0, 00 are used for soft wheat, while semolina and semola are used for coarse and fine grain size of hard wheat. A little bit unusual , but no one seems to refer to durum wheat in numerical sizes.

Comment: @Kermilli looks like that's correct. Semolina is the coarse, single ground *Triticum durum* properly, but it seems you can also make semolina from soft wheat (*Triticum aestivum*), though this has to be named differently in some places and is distinguishable by colour. Italian has *semola di grano duro* for the coarse and the fine is *... grano rimacinata* (grama = grains, the ground bit, not the seeds in this case), so I think *semola* is the Italian for semolina in English.